# The Sinister Toy

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> My name is Gabee and I
> live in Nebraska. Now,
> my friend Ito R. Caxti
> and I have thousands
> of like-new toys. So, um,
> Tue. eve we stopped at
> a mall where plastic
> pet giraffes rested
> in an aisle. “We each, uh,
> really shouldn’t own
> such possessions. No,
> thousands of toys is
> a tad much,” I declared.

> We took ‘O’, a late train,
> to Ito & my house to eat
> beans. “So Gabee, there
> is one unknit toy, big,
> kinda scares me. So, um…
> let me know best ploy
> to control 1 sinister
> toy which bites hard.”

> “Well,” I said, “buy a cage.
> That is what I bought
> for a rabid tiger and
> falcon. Now they can’t
> flee or escape at all!”

What animal should Ito keep in a cage? (16)

By the way, you should know that his snakes are always twisting in odd directions.

Here is a list of Ito’s toy animals. He has more than one of some. Good luck!

alpaca
ant
ants
ape
asp
auk
bee
boa
cat
coati
cow
deer
doe
eagle
eel
eels
emu
ewe
falcon
foal
gibbons
giraffes
grouse
hen
koala
komodo
lion
llama
locust
loon
moose
moth
newt
ocelot
orca
owl
rats
ray
sheep
slug
snail
snake
sow
stork
swan
tapirs
tiger
toucan
tsetse
tuna

Comment: This one is easier but it was fun to make and may be a welcome break for those struggling to escape the laboratory : )

Comment: It's not a thousand, but I think 59 toy animals is still pretty excessive... (Figured out the first step - have to sleep soon, though, so partial coming up.)

Comment: Update: accidentally solved it!

Comment: This is an impressive puzzle

Comment: Just out of interest, how long did it take you to make this puzzle?

Comment: It was 3 evenings, must have been around 8 hrs? It was fun to build.

Comment: "This one is easier" Really?? Is this what is called easy on this site nowadays?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The writing seems very strange.

> In fact, each line of it has *exactly* 18 letters in it. So it could help to remove the spaces, punctuation, and numbers, and just look at it as an 18-wide grid.

And there's another curious thing:

> You may have already noticed that some of the names seem to hide animals in them - Ga**bee**, It**o R. Ca**xti.

That's because...

> this is actually a word search! Each of the given animals can be found in the resulting grid, some of them multiple times:
>  [image]
>  ...except for SNAKE.

But this isn't the answer to the puzzle. It's not 16 letters long, and also,

> the puzzle mentions that his snakes are twisting in odd directions. And we *can* find SNAKEs in the grid -- if we allow the words to bend!
>  [image]

So, now what?

> Well, what letters have been 'encaged'? There appear to be exactly sixteen single letters that are surrounded by animals:
>  [image]
>  And these anagram to **TYRANNOSAURUS REX** - that could definitely be a "big, scar[y]" toy that "bites hard"!

Comment: You help Ito wrestle the animal into its cage, but not before it managed to eat an ahi and an ox. At least the others are safe!

Comment: Appreciate the sheer perseverance!